# Identify this organism

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone identify this organism please? Often I see it inside my home on the walls moving very slowly.
[please click for a better-quality image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbBB.jpg)

some more info:

- Geographical location: India (north part)
- Image taken recently (March 2018)
- Size of organism: about 1 cm in size.

[image]

Comment: You have to add your geographical location, what the time of year was, the approximate size *etc*. Also, can't you possibly provide a higher quality picture? This one is kind of grainy.